# ant is not recognized as an internal or external

Tags: android, cordova, ant

So my original problem was trying to add the android platform to phonegap. It ended up with command failed exit code 8. So after hunting around, downloading android SDK, adding it to my PATH, downloading ant and adding that to my path, it still is not working.

I did not add any spaces between semi-colons in my path, or add ANT_HOME as a user variable rather than a system. I've looked as other similar question but nothing I try seems to work.

Comment: What are you getting when you run `ant` in command prompt?

Comment: Also run this in command prompt for us to help you debug `echo %PATH%`. (that is, assuming you are using Windows).

Comment: Which OS are you trying to install on Windows/linus/MAC? You need to provide more info. Detail all the step that you have taken to install and run cordova commands.

Comment: @bhargavg When running ant in command prompt I get `Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed`

Comment: @frank I am on Windows 7 I installed Phonegap on Node.js. Whenever I tried to `phonegap build android` or `phonegap run android` I ended up with error exit code 8. I read that it could be that I didn't have Android SDKs installed so I installed the platform and build tools from the android website and added platform-tools and tools to my path. Then I downloaded ant from the apache ant website and installed it, and added it to my path as well

Comment: @MarikoShimoda you need to install Java JDK as well. Only JRE will not work. Also when you install the JDK add it to the system path `PATH` and also add a new envrionment variable `JAVA_HOME` referring to the new installed JDK path.

Comment: I downloaded JDK 1.6 and added it to my path and created the environment variable. Now I am getting `Buildfile:build.xml does not exist! Build Failed`

Comment: It turns out I had installed the latest Android SDK when it required 19... whoops. Thanks everyone for your help!